# Remove Lot of white spaces in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write custom tokenizer:

```
print(re.sub(' ',"\n",(re.sub('\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]|\\\\|\\/|\\\"|\\\'|\\,|\\=|\\(|\\)|\\:|\\||\\-|\\*|\\!|\\;|\\<|\\>|\\,|\\?|//@'," ",str))))
```

Output:

```
America




Category
States
of
the
United
States




Category
Southern
United
States





Link
FA
mk
```

Many new lines being inserted. I'm trying to write an optimized code to remove all empty lines with regular expressions without going into each and everydetails. I'm really worried about the performance of the program. I've lines over 100 Billion. So, I'm bit worried about time of execution. Any suggessions?

I'm trying to make output as below:

```
America
Category
States
of
the
United
States
Category
Southern
United
States
Link
FA
mk
```

Comment: Why in the world did you label this `java`?

Comment: Your regex pattern would be enormously easier to read (and probably to write and maintain) if you use a "raw" string: e.g. `r"\no\t\hing \\in \a \raw\ stri\ng i\s es\ca\ped"` (which will be a string with twelve backslashes in it).

Comment: Why do you write two backslashes before ``{`` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `join()` and `split()` methods:

```
print " ".join(your_string.split())
```

**Output:**

```
America Category States of the United States Category Southern United States Link FA mk
```

**Edit:**

To get each word in a different line, use `"\n"` instead of `" "`:

```
print "\n".join(a.split())
```

Comment: should be `'\n'.join...`, not with a space

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub('\n{2,}', '\n', str)`

will remove empty lines